# Pass data across modules in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using one module (m1)  for signin/signup (index.html) and another module (m2) for my main page content (main.HTML)

Since both are two different HTML pages, I used two modules. I stored the user email ID in a service (s1) of  m1 during sign up. Now I need the email I'd in my main page.  I did the following,

Injected m1 to m2 
angular.module('m2', ['m1']);

Injected s1 to m2's controller.

Accessed the s1's function in m2's controller to retrieve the stored email Id. (It can be some other data also)

When main.HTML loads, m1 and s1 are constructed freshly, so I am loosing the data.  It seems, the injected modules will always be freshly created. How to fix this?

Comment: javascript is not persistent between page loads. You need to store the data either on server or in sessionStorage and check for it in both apps

Comment: storing signup/login data in localstorage is better than storing it in session Storage.

Comment: @RahulArora for what reason? Really depends on level of security wanted

Comment: sessionStorage is lost once user closes tab, Unless you want to logout the user if he closes tab.

Comment: Can you provide some code to show what you have done? A fiddler or a plubkr would be helpful too.

Comment: Temporarily I am going with local storage like IndexedDB.